# how can i access the button id in activity from fragment

Tags: java, android, android-studio

How to access button id in an activity.

Activity

```
  @Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.fragment_meter);
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 23) {
        checkLocationPermission();
    }



 FragmentManager fragmentManager =  getSupportFragmentManager();
    FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
    Fragment map = new Map();
    fragmentTransaction.add(R.id.fragment_container, map);
    fragmentTransaction.commit();

 ...
}
```

Fragment

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {




  if (view == null) {
        view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_map, container, false);

        Button button = (Button)getActivity().findViewById(R.id.btnStop);

    }
```

How to implement setOnClickListener method of btnStop in my code fragment?

Comment: Let me know if i understand it correctly that you want to access your button in Activity and not in Fragment?? If no then simply use button.setOnClickListener() after you cast the button

Comment: yes, I just want access Button in Activity from Fragment. I just want to implement setOnClickListener of btnStop in Fragment

Comment: You need to use callback from `Fragment` to `Activity`. Simplest way to get example is - right click on package -> New -> Fragment -> Fragment (Blank) and make sure you select "Include interface callbacks" checkBox

Comment: Using callback you don't need to find id in activity, just handle click at fragment and pass event to activity using interface

Comment: from that how can i implement the setOnClickListener()  of btnStop. Can you provide me a example

Comment: If all you want is to perform click then you can pass the OnClickListener to the Fragment in the constructor and implement onClicklistener in Activity, and when you set the click listener in fragment pass the click listener from the constructor.

Answer (score -1):

add this to fragment:

```
final View.OnClickListener btnClick = new View.OnClickListener() {
                           public void onClick(View v){
                               //button clicked 
                           }
                     }
```

add this to activity `onCreate`:

```
Button button = (Button)getActivity().findViewById(R.id.btnStop);
button.setOnClickListener(map.btnClick );
```

---

**another way:**

add this to fragment:

```
Button btnStop;
```

add this to `onCreate` of Activity:

```
map.btnStop = (Button)getActivity().findViewById(R.id.btnStop);
```

Then in any event listener of fragment that is called after `onCreate` of Activity (for example `onActivityCreated` and `onStart`) you have access to the `btnStop` and you can set `onClick` listener for it.

Comment: I just want access the Button in Activity from Fragment

Comment: is this to access Activity button from fragment. i'm little bit confused can you explain it more.

Comment: @Helaka yes it results accessing the Activity button in fragment (especially the second way). in the answer i have written the location of codes if you read carefully you will understand.

Answer (score -1):

```
You can create a method in the activity, probably like

public void yourMethod() {

button.performClick();// you can access all the components present in your activity

}

Now create an instance of the activity in the fragment and access this method.

YourActivity activityInstance = (YourActivity) getActivity();

And then you can access the method using the isntance of the activity like

activityInstance.yourMethod();
```

Whenever you want to perform a click function, you just have to call the funciton.

Comment: It looks like you understood it incorrect, user wants to access fragment button in activity and not the reverse.

Comment: I don't think so. The user is asking to access a button that is present in the activity from the fragment !